# @gorhom/bottom-sheet modal not opening on android with apk

Tags: android, react-native, modal-dialog, apk, bottom-sheet

I am using [@gorhom/bottom-sheet](https://github.com/gorhom/react-native-bottom-sheet) package in a React Native app (with Expo) to open a bottom sheet modal when a button is pressed.

Everything is working fine using expo start on iOS and Android: when I click on the button, the modal shows up, and when I swipe it down, the modal disappears.

But when I build a signed .apk file to install it on my Android phone, the modal does not show. No error, no message, nothing.

I am using the following dependencies, and I have followed the extra instructions regarding the bottom sheet modal & react-native-gesture-handler/react-native-reanimated:

- "@gorhom/bottom-sheet": "^4.4.7"
- "react-native": "^0.72.4"
- "react-native-gesture-handler": "^2.12.1"
- "react-native-reanimated": "~3.3.0"
- "react-native-safe-area-context": "4.6.3"
- "expo": "^49.0.8"

The App:

```js
import { BottomSheetModalProvider, BottomSheetModal } from '@gorhom/bottom-sheet';
import { Button } from '@rneui/themed';
import { useRef, useCallback, useMemo } from 'react';
import { View, Text, StyleSheet } from 'react-native';
import { GestureHandlerRootView } from 'react-native-gesture-handler';

export default function App() {
    const bottomSheetModalRef = useRef(null);
    const snapPoints = useMemo(() => ['50%'], []);

    const handlePresentModalPress = useCallback(() => {
        bottomSheetModalRef.current?.present();
    }, []);

    const handleSheetChanges = useCallback((index) => {
        console.log('handleSheetChanges', index);
    }, []);

    // renders
    return (
        <GestureHandlerRootView style={{ flex: 1 }}>
            <BottomSheetModalProvider>
                <View style={styles.container}>
                    <Button
                        onPress={handlePresentModalPress}
                        title="Present Modal"
                        color="black"
                    />
                    <BottomSheetModal
                        ref={bottomSheetModalRef}
                        index={0}
                        snapPoints={snapPoints}
                        onChange={handleSheetChanges}
                    >
                        <View style={styles.contentContainer}>
                            <Text>Awesome </Text>
                        </View>
                    </BottomSheetModal>
                </View>
            </BottomSheetModalProvider>
        </GestureHandlerRootView>
    );
};

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    container: {
        flex: 1,
        padding: 24,
        justifyContent: 'center',
        backgroundColor: 'grey',
    },
    contentContainer: {
        flex: 1,
        alignItems: 'center',
    },
});
```

Any idea what could be the issue?

Answer (score 0):

I was experiencing the same issue as you
I suggest you are building with
"eas build -p android --profile preview"

Try building with
"eas build"
that will generate an .aab file
then use aab to apk app converter (download from google play store) to convert the generated .aab file to apk
install the apk and that should do it